# Read and make calculations with textfield input SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I want to make calculations with inputs from 2 different Textfields and put the output in a Text. See code:

```
@State var input1: String = ""

@State var input2: String = ""

var calculation : Double {
    let calculationProduct = Double(input1) * Double(input2)
    return calculationProduct
}

var body: some View {
VStack{
 TextField("", text: $input1)
 TextField("", text: $input1)

Text("\(calculation)")
}
```

The problem is the code won't compile, i get different compile errors, for example: "Binary operator '*' cannot be applied to two 'Double?' operands".

What goes wrong?

Comment: Whatever is typed into the TextFields might not convert to a Double. So the return from each conversion is an optional. You can’t multiply optional in case they’re nil.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Double(input1)` returns `String?` because it's not guaranteed to work. e.g. `Double("1abc")`

We can use `guard let` or `if let` or even a nil coalescing operator `??` to handle this. But for the following example we will gracefully handle it using `guard let`.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var input1: String = ""
    @State var input2: String = ""

    var calculation : Double {
        guard let m = Double(input1), let n  = Double(input2) else { return 0 }
        return m * n
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("", text: $input1)
            TextField("", text: $input2)

            Text("\(calculation)")
        }
    }
}
```

---

#### EDIT

As per your comments, there are multiple ways to show "Error" on invalid inputs, or the answer upto 2 decimal point.
For this example, lets change the `result` to a computed `String` property both these these cases, as such:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var input1: String = ""
    @State var input2: String = ""

    var calculation: String {
        //check if both fields have text else no need for message
        guard input1.isEmpty == false, input2.isEmpty == false else { return "" }

        //check if both are numbers else we need to print "Error"
        guard let m = Double(input1), let n  = Double(input2) else { return "Error" }

        let product = m * n
        return String(format: "%.2f", product)
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("Enter First Number", text: $input1)
                .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
            TextField("Enter Second Number", text: $input2)
                .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())

            Text(calculation)
        }
    }
}
```

PS: If you want to ensure only numbers can be typed then you should think about applying the `.keyboardType(.decimalPad)` modifier on the `TextField`s.

Comment: It works, but I don't want to return 0, but I want to return a string "Error". I also use a specifier in the Text ("%.2f"), this give a incorrect number if  m*n = for example 1000. It present 1000....

Comment: @JohanKornet Updated the answer. Minor changes required :)

Comment: The code works and I applied: ".keyboardType(.decimalPad) modifier on the TextFields".  But it is still possible to put in an incorrect number for example: 1,..2060,,.562...     I think I need a formatter so the user can only put in correct numbers? Or do i need a validator?  SwiftUI is a new language and can't find such thinks to solve.

Comment: When i calculate for example 11 * 20 it gives 220....  and not 220.00. I think this is a bug in SwiftUI or does anyone else know how this is possible?

Comment: @JohanKornet You mean literally `220...` (with the three dots)? If that's the case then probably the text label width is not enough. The example given above shows `220.00` properly for 11 * 20.

Comment: I tried with a modifier for Text: .frame(width: 400), and the problem is solved!

Comment: I hope someone can help me with my question about the Formatter or Validator for the Textfield?  See question above here.

Answer (score 2):

@Johankornet, you have probably figured this out by now, but the below code will work for decimal entries:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var textFieldEntry: Double = 1.0

    let formatter: NumberFormatter = {
            let formatter = NumberFormatter()
            formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
            return formatter
        }()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("title", value: $textFieldEntry, formatter:        formatter).padding()
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

To see it working, i made an entire app with this main file:

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct testTextFieldWithNumericFormattingApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
```

formatter.decimalstyle = .decimal restricts the TextField input to decimals only. Type in something thats not a decimal, like "abc", hit return and the input is ignored. This input field can accept scientific notation numbers as input, but the TextField will display as a decimal so very small scientific notation inputs, such as 3e-7 will be displayed as zero.

@JohanKornet, you have probably found other more elegant solutions for this problem by now, but if not maybe this will help:)